# Electron package - how to write/read files

Tags: node.js, electron

I have file `test.txt` in my root directory of app. When I run my app with command `npm start`, I can write to my file without any problem, but when I make package using electron packager, writing text to my file is not possible anymore - I got error

`Error: EACCES: permission denied, open './test.txt'`

For this, I'm using node.js filesystem:

```
fs.writeFile("./test.txt",text,function(err){

    if(err) {
        return alert(err);
    }

    alert("saved");

});
```

How is possible to make this working? And is possible to include some extra folder in my app after package process? Thanks for your help!

Comment: How are you exactly generating package? I've used `electron-packager ./ test --electronVersion=1.6.5` command and the generated exe can write file in its folder without problem

Comment: @pergy I'm using `electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't really found out what the problem was, so I tried another solution, which works for me (my main aim was to save data to some local memory of app).

I used npm package `electron-store` which is really easy to use.

You can get it by typing this to terminal

```
npm install electron-store
```

More info about it here: [Electron store](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store)

Hope it helps someone else too :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are [a lot of options to choose to package your electron app in 2019](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution#application-distribution), so in case you come to this question like I did and are using electron-builder, please try my suggestion below.

If you are using [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) to package your application and need to read/write a file that is stored within your solution, you can add it to your **files** property in your `package.json`. The properties in this file property are files that are copied when packaging your electron app - [reference](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#files).

In my example, I was reading/writing to **file.json**.

```
let fs = require("fs");

fs.writeFile("./file.json", "data to file", "utf-8", (error, data) => {
    if (error){
        console.error("error: " + error);
    }
});
```

My folder structure looked like this.

```
parent-folder
    app/
    assets/
    configs/
    images/
    resources/
    ...
    file.json
```

My app was not working after I packed it until I added the following **file.json** in my "build" property in my `package.json`.

```
"build": {
    "productName": "MyApp",
    "appId": "org.dev.MyApp",
    "files": [
        "app/dist/",
        "app/app.html",
        "app/main.prod.js",
        "app/main.prod.js.map",
        "package.json",
        "file.json", // << added this line
    ],
    //...
}
```