# fs.writeFileSync not working after build electron app with electron-buider

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, electron

im working with electron like below

```
 var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'test.json')));
data.push('test data')
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'test.json'), JSON.stringify(data));
```

before build with electron-builder, every thing work correctly, test.json change fs.writeFileSync but when i build app with electron-builder fs.readFileSync still working correctly but writeFileSync not work. test.json does not change when i add some data

Comment: A relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027816/electron-package-how-to-write-read-files

Comment: @jfriend00 it still not work, i add "test.json" in package.json but it still not work